# plots and codes not showing in KNIT to HTML

Tags: graph

### title: "Project"
output: html_document
date: "2024-01-18"

[text](https://stackoverflow.com)

**I am new to coding, So in R studio  while trying to knit to html i didn't get codes and plots in my html files. I need solution for these. ****